# How do I get Flatlist to scroll item to 1

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I wanted a full screen list of videos, but I scroll up and down extremely fast.I wish he only had item +1 or -1 at a time, not so many item slides.
Do you have any good ideas? Flatlist doesn't seem to have this property.You can't limit the number of slides
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recently had the same problem as you, which I want FlatList to scroll one index in one scroll.

First I look at the FlatList props, it seems there are no props that can solve my problem. Then I look up with the ScrollView props, because FlatList inherits ScrollView props.

I found a `disableintervalmomentum` props which can simply resolve my problem.
See more describe at [here](https://reactnative.dev/docs/scrollview#disableintervalmomentum).

So you can just add the props and set it to true like below:

```
 <FlatList
  // other props
  disableintervalmomentum:{true}
 />
```

Comment: Yes, thank you very much for your help. I did use disableintervalmomentum: {true}

Comment: Thank you. i  have same issue. i solve it

Answer (score 1):

Can you explain a bit more. For Scrolling one at a time you can use Viewpager. That will be a better approach. I did some modifications that might work.

```
  <FlatList
    snapToAlignment={"top"}
    viewabilityConfig={{ itemVisiblePercentThreshold: 90 }}
    pagingEnabled={true}
    data={dayOptions}
    decelerationRate={"fast"}
    renderItem={({ item }) => <Render item={item} />}
  />
```

You can try one more thing on         `scrollEnabled={false}` and scroll it by click on some icon.

Comment: In fact, I've achieved video playback effects with FlatList, but I'm not satisfied with its gesture scrolling effect. Since I swipe multiple items each time I swipe flatList, my idea is to limit the scrolling effect. Using flatList, I only slide tiem one unit down or up

Comment: I think I'm going to have to override this, and try to implement it with Viewpager。Alright. Thank you